# Getting value repeated for next year if value is recurring

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a record for project and release number and I need to repeat the row in next year if value is recurring.
First image is showing the data that I have it[image]

My expected output is:
[image]

Explanation of output: In year 2017 value_type ITA has frequency as Recurring so, This value should be repeated in all next year(i.e 2018, 2019 and 2020). like that in year 2018 OC and PA is recurring so it also need to repeated in 2019 and 2020.

For that I created a new view for only recurring value and tried to join that view with base table. But it is not giving me proper result.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How about other columns (RUN_RATE)? Do they repeat? And will you have it repeat forever?

Comment: Where does it stop? Perhaps better to have a `Repeat_Until` field that has a year where the repeating finishes.

Comment: Only Recurring value rows are going to repeated...@DVT

Comment: It will stop at the max(years)....In my project the max year is 2020 then it will display record till 2020.....@mendosi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DECLARE @EndYear INT =2020 --Also you can get from data by MAX(Year)
    ;WITH tb(PROJECT_ID,RELEASE_NO,[YEAR],VALUE_TYPE,VAL_DES,COST,RUN_TATE,FREQUENCY)
    AS(
       SELECT 111,1,2016,'IT','EXPENSE',0,NULL,NULL UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2016,'IR','INCOME',10000,NULL,NULL UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2016,'OC','EXPENSE',-200000,NULL,NULL UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2016,'Vendor','EXPENSE',-5000,NULL,NULL UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2017,'BC','INCOME',200000,NULL,NULL UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2017,'ITA','INCOME',5000,5000,'Recurring' UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2017,'OC','EXPENSE',-200000,NULL,NULL UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2018,'OC','EXPENSE',-10000,-10000,'Recurring' UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2018,'PA','INCOME',100000,100000,'Recurring' UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2019,'icc','INCOME',500,NULL,NULL UNION
       SELECT 111,1,2020,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL 
    ),Recurring AS (
       SELECT tb.PROJECT_ID,tb.RELEASE_NO,tb.VALUE_TYPE,tb.VAL_DES,MIN([YEAR]) AS StartYear,MAX(COST) AS COST,MAX(tb.RUN_TATE) AS RUN_TATE
       FROM tb WHERE FREQUENCY='Recurring' 
       GROUP BY tb.PROJECT_ID,tb.RELEASE_NO,tb.VALUE_TYPE,tb.VAL_DES
    )
    SELECT * FROM tb union
    SELECT r.PROJECT_ID,r.RELEASE_NO,n.number AS [YEAR],r.VALUE_TYPE,r.VAL_DES,r.COST,r.RUN_TATE,NULL AS FREQUENCY FROM 
    Recurring AS r 
    OUTER  APPLY (
       SELECT sv.number FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS sv WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN r.StartYear+1 AND @EndYear
    )n
```

```
PROJECT_ID  RELEASE_NO  YEAR        VALUE_TYPE VAL_DES COST        RUN_TATE    FREQUENCY
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ------- ----------- ----------- ---------
111         1           2016        IR         INCOME  10000       NULL        NULL
111         1           2016        IT         EXPENSE 0           NULL        NULL
111         1           2016        OC         EXPENSE -200000     NULL        NULL
111         1           2016        Vendor     EXPENSE -5000       NULL        NULL
111         1           2017        BC         INCOME  200000      NULL        NULL
111         1           2017        ITA        INCOME  5000        5000        Recurring
111         1           2017        OC         EXPENSE -200000     NULL        NULL
111         1           2018        ITA        INCOME  5000        5000        NULL
111         1           2018        OC         EXPENSE -10000      -10000      Recurring
111         1           2018        PA         INCOME  100000      100000      Recurring
111         1           2019        icc        INCOME  500         NULL        NULL
111         1           2019        ITA        INCOME  5000        5000        NULL
111         1           2019        OC         EXPENSE -10000      -10000      NULL
111         1           2019        PA         INCOME  100000      100000      NULL
111         1           2020        NULL       NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
111         1           2020        ITA        INCOME  5000        5000        NULL
111         1           2020        OC         EXPENSE -10000      -10000      NULL
111         1           2020        PA         INCOME  100000      100000      NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Nolan Shang